# How to pick IEnumerable<T> instead of List<T> from an ICollection<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have the following lines that work as supposed to.

```
Dictionary<Guid, List<T>> dictionary = source.ToDictionary(
  element => element.Id,
  element => element.Ts.ToList());
```

However, I'd like the first line to use *IEnumerable*, which creates an error of type mismatch.

```
Dictionary<Guid, IEnumerable<T>> dictionary = source.ToDictionary( ... );
```

Using *ToArray* instead of *ToList* won't help me (getting the same error, plus I've learned not to use arrays in C# unless really, really required) And as far I can tell, the type of *Ts* is *ICollection*.

Is it possible to convert the whole shabang the way I wish without going hardcore and using casting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid casting, you can use the [`AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb335435%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) extension method, which would return the correct type, but also hide the original instance/implementation behind an anonymous enumerable.

I would personally just use `element => element.Ts as IEnumerable<T>` though, to avoid calling extra method only to satisfy the limited generics inference.

Answer (score 5):

That's because `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is not covariant. So you can't pick `Dictionary<string, List<T>>` and cast it to `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<T>>` even though `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`. Why? Consider following code:

```
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<int>> myDict = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
myDict.Add("key", new HashSet<int>());
```

From compiler perspective that would be totally ok, because `HashSet<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`. But the dictionary is expecting the value to be `List<T>`!

You can do a cast in `ToDictionary` method:

```
Dictionary<Guid, IEnumerable<T>> dictionary = source.ToDictionary(
  element => element.Id,
  element => (IEnumerable<T>)element.Ts.ToList());
```

or provide generic type parameters to `ToDictionary` call:

```
Dictionary<Guid, IEnumerable<T>> dictionary = source.ToDictionary<Guid, IEnumerable<T>>(
  element => element.Id,
  element => element.Ts.ToList());
```

Comment: Hah, I totally forgot about the explicit type annotation. That's the winner for me.

Answer (score 3):

Use `AsEnumerable()`, which is a handy Linq method that just returns the source cast to `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
Dictionary<Guid, IEnumerable<T>> dictionary = source.ToDictionary(
  element => element.Id,
  element => element.Ts.AsEnumerable());
```

you could also try casting:

```
Dictionary<Guid, IEnumerable<T>> dictionary = source.ToDictionary(
  element => element.Id,
  element => (IEnumerable<T>)(element.Ts));
```